# Accessing object properties in another function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have been reading through a ton of questions posted and cannot find the answer to my problem.  I have used JavaScript as procedural for about 2 years now and have decided it is now time for me to bite the bullet and get cleaner object-oriented code.  I have declared an object as defined below:

```
function Driver(driverName, startAddress){
    this.driverName = driverName;
    this.address = address;
    this.inventory = 0;
    this.latCoord = 0;
    this.lngCoord = 0;
}
```

and have built functions for the Driver object by using the `Driver.prototype.functionName = function(){};` syntax.  That all is fine.

Then I declare a global variable `FULL_LIST = [];` and have a function as follows:

```
function initialize(){
    // init geocoder
    GEOCODER = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // init map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }
    MAP = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // init list of all drivers
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions/getDriverInfo.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var names = data.names,
                addresses = data.addresses;
            for (var i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var driver = new Driver(names[i], addresses[i]);
                FULL_LIST.push(driver);
            };
        }
    });

    run();
}
```

My big problem comes from the fact that I want to make a function like the following:

```
function run(){
    // plot points
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
    for(var i=0; i<FULL_LIST.length; i++){
        var node = FULL_LIST[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: MAP,
            position: {
                node.latCoord,
                node.lngCoord
            },
            title: node.driverName
        });
        bounds.extend({
            node.latCoord,
            node.lngCoord
        });
        MAP.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Because `run()` has no way of knowing that `node` is a Driver, I don't think it expects the `.latCoord` and I get a `"TypeError unexpected ."` on that line. Is there any way to cast `node` as a Driver? Is there a problem with not having a larger scale namespace wrapping it all? Or do I have an entirely messed up view of the problem?

Thanks to @fgb for his insight that the issue was a Google maps syntax issue.  For those pointing out the async effects of AJAX, I am aware and that was not related to the issue I was having.  I cut out a ton of my code for simplicity sake and with that I excluded a number of other ajax calls and dropped the `run()` fxn right in.

However, my original question still stands, albeit somewhat altered.  Why does this work? I would have thought that because the object and its properties are defined in a different function that the `run` function wouldn't know that `.latCoord` was a potential property for an object because at no point does the system know to expect a `Driver` object.  Wouldn't this be a big issue in something like c++?

Comment: It all has to happen upon `success` since AJAX is Asynchronous.

Comment: you're calling `run()` before the ajax success function is complete, try moving `run` inside the callback

Comment: Isn't `{ node.latCoord, node.lngCoord }` a syntax error? Try `{ lat: node.latCoord, lng: node.lngCoord }`

Comment: @fgb thanks you answered the problem, but if any of you see my edits above, my main question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a constructor elsewhere, but once you create an object with it, you end up with a self-contained object. The object knows what properties it has and doesn't need a separate definition anywhere. This is different from languages like c++ where you need access to a class definition to use an instance.

Types in JavaScript are more flexible than in some other languages. It has the concept of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) where the types of objects are implicitly defined based on how they're used rather than strict type definitions.

So you could throw in some object literals like `{ latCoord: 5, lngCoord: 10, driverName: 'Name' }` into `FULL_LIST`, and the `run` function will use them the same way as the constructor created objects.